# do generic type param shadow reference types? (java)

Tags: java, generics, type-parameter, reference-type, shadowing

Let's say we have the following scenario:

```
public class SomeClass {

}
```

And now we have a generic class with type parameter `SomeClass` instead of `T`.

```
public class GenericClass <SomeClass> {
    List<SomeClass> list;

    public GenericClass() {
         list = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void add(SomeClass obj) {
         list.add(obj);
    }
}
```

Will the type parameter `SomeClass` shadow the reference datatype `SomeClass` in the whole `GenericClass`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes**. That's a *name shadow* in this context. You can still disambiguate with the fully qualified class name (as long you as you use a package, as you should). Also, this is a good argument for using conventional short type names for your generic types.

Comment: To expand: Conventionally​ we use single uppercase letters for type parameters​. Common: `T`for "type", followed​ by `U`, `V`, ... for multiple parameters​, `<K, V>` for key-value pairs, `E` for "element", `<L, R>` for left-right pairs.

Comment: Also common, first letter of an upper-bound type, e.g., `<N extends Node>`.

Answer (score 2):

In a word - yes, it will shadow `SomeClass`. You could still use the fully qualified class name (e.g., `com.exmaple.SomeClass`) to reference it, though.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I couldn't mark both (yours and elliotts) as the right answer.